# the obscene bird of night by jose donoso

Tags: epub, conversion, file-format, image, website

I have been looking for Jose Donoso; The Obscene Bird of Night english translated searchable PDF version, the one I have is just image turned into pdf, does any one has so I can use.

thanks for your time and attention.

BR